# Regarding sklearn adjusted_rand_score in k means clustering

Tags: scikit-learn, clustering

A dataset is given consisting of target class as categorical.K means was applied to it for clustering the data and got the corresponding cluster labels.   But how to put the values in adjusted Rand score function as it is taking the true values and predicted values and the true values are in categorical format.  I tried converting the target class true data to numeric by using LabelEncoder but when passed to adjusted Rand score it is coming low.
  Please suggest a better and correct approach

Comment: LabelEncodet sounds right, and so does a low score for k-means... It's not a particularly good clustering algorithm, and most data sets are not labeled for clustering either.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse so the number of unique labels on dataset cannot decide the number of clusters for k means clustering?

Comment: If you had the labels, you don't *need* to cluster. This evaluation is just good for proof-of-concept.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse yes just for validation purposes can we cross check the number of clusters we got with actual labels?would it always be same

Comment: No. The optimal number of clusters will often be much higher because of outliers and other structures than the labels. Validating with class labels is usually pretty much nonsense.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse thanks but when I am applying it to my dataset and using elbow method for finding optimal number of clusters am getting them same as number of labels

Comment: The Elbow method is vague and unreliable, and people don't understand how to read it. Do *not* use it.

Comment: Ok what is the alternative method to find optimal number of clusters ?

Comment: Define "optimal".

Comment: Where the clustering evaluation metrics are the best

Comment: That is a circular definition, isn't it? Or do you mean the best ARI? then just choose the k which maximizes the ARI, as you are 'cheating' anyway. You are not doing real clustering anyway, but approximating the labeling.

Comment: From optimal I meant to find k with elbow method or silhouette analysis

Comment: But neither elbow not Silhouette usually finds thenmoat useful result.

Comment: ok which method is most suitable for finding optimal k?

Comment: There is no such thing as the "optimal k". The only way to really use this is to try multiple.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse ok got it thanks